# Salvar resultados de uma função em uma variável Ionic 3 + Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, return, firestore

Como fazer para salvar o resultado obtido em r.get('quant') em uma variavel e retornar o seu valor, pois o primeiro console.log mostra os dados que eu obtive, mas o segundo não, e o return quant sempre mostra undefined no console.

```
getQuantProduto(id, item){
var quant;
this.afs.collection(this.pedidos).doc(id).collection(this.itens).
doc(item).ref.get().then(function(r){
    quant = r.get('quant');
    console.log(quant);
})
console.log('quant');
return quant;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Como a função é assíncrona, o segundo `console.log` e o `return` são executados antes da função `this.afs.collection(this.pedidos).doc(id).collection(this.itens).
doc(item).ref.get()`. Para retornar o valor, você precisa colocar o `return` dentro da função:

```
getQuantProduto(id, item){
  var quant;
  this.afs.collection(this.pedidos).doc(id).collection(this.itens).
  doc(item).ref.get().then(function(r){
    quant = r.get('quant');
    console.log(quant);
    return quant;
})
```

Comment: obrigado pelo feedback, porém quando eu faço o seguinte código: this.a = this.provider.getQuantProduto(123, abc), não consigo obter nenhum retorno ainda

Comment: O `console.log(quant);` mostra algum valor?

Comment: Sim, ele mostra corretamente o valor que eu busco, porém o return não retorna esse valor, somente retorna undefined

Comment: Se ele mostrou o valor correto no `console.log(quant)`, a função deve ter respondido com o valor correto. Veja se você não está tentando exibir o valor de `this.a` antes da execução da função (assíncrona).

Comment: Talvez seja isso, no caso como posso corrigir esse problema?